# How to scroll a Win2D canvas content?

Tags: c#, uwp, scroll, custom-scrolling

Im developing an app that draws Grid of images using win2d CanvasVirtualControl. I want to scroll the draw content so that the previously drawn tiles will be scrolled to somepostion and a new tiles of images will be painted. Currenty achieved it by usig PointerWheelChanged, But Getting jerky scroll not a smooth one.

Comment: Please follow the tagging gudielines and don't put tags in your question title. If you're new here, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask], along with the associated help topics. The site's requirements and guidelines are stricter than most others, so it would benefit you to understand them.

Comment: If you want to perform a scrolling task within the Win2D control, you could use ScrollViewer control and put Win2d control in it, after that you need to make sure that the Height property of the win2d control is greater than the height of the ScrollViewer, so that the scroll bar will be displayed.

Comment: It will not workout our app is huge data handling and painting app.. currently we are painting datas on demans depending on current viewport. i tried with poiterwheelchanged wheeldata which is also inconsistent

Comment: Could you please check the value of [ManipulationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode?view=winrt-20348#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationMode) of CanvasVirtualControl?